# É Possível Fazer Duas Autenticações no Mesmo Projeto Laravel?

Tags: laravel

No Laravel temos a função `Auth()` que trabalha com toda a parte que uma autenticação precisa.

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que terá login no Front-End (para utilização individual do cliente) e no Back-End (no sistema de gerenciamento do site).

É possível usar a função `Auth()` para realizar duas autenticações no mesmo projeto ?

Uso o **Laravel 5.1**.

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma tabela com permissões?

Comment: Não. São tabelas com conteúdos (colunas) muito distintas, não quero misturar clientes com usuários de um sistema.

Comment: https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth Da uma olhada nesse projeto.

Comment: O Laravel 5.2 implementou o guard, que serve exatamente para isto que você precisa ;), nas versões anteriores utilize o MultiAuth do Kbwebs: https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth

Comment: Deu certo @Rafael ...

Comment: Você quer que o mesmo usuário utilize dois logins diferentes ao mesmo tempo? é isso? se não for isso tem jeito.